# AutoMapper mapping nested List object

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to Map a nested List with my DTO object, however its not working. here is what I tried. everything returns null. Error I get is: **An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code**

```
public class ordersview_Dto
{
    public int orderID { get; set; }
    public string orderNumber { get; set; }
    public float? orderTotal { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public List<ProductsDTO> ProductsDTO { get; set; }

}

public class ProductsDTO
{


    public int id { get; set; }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }

 }
```

This is how I am mapping:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<OrderHeader, ordersview_Dto>()
        .ForMember(h => h.ProductsDTO, k => k.MapFrom((m => m.orderLines)));

        IEnumerable<OrderHeader> ordersList = new OrdersRepository().getOrders();

        IEnumerable<ordersview_Dto> ordersFlow = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OrderHeader>, IEnumerable<ordersview_Dto>>(ordersList);
```

I am sure problem relies in this line: **.ForMember(h => h.ProductsDTO, k => k.MapFrom((m => m.orderLines)));** ProductsDTO and OrderLines both are Lists.

here is my OrderHeader Class:

```
 public class OrderHeader
    {

        public OrderHeader()
        {
            // Set any defaults here;
            orderLines = new List<OrderLines>();
        }


        public float? SubTotal { get; set; }

        public float? Shipping { get; set; }

        public string ShipMethod { get; set; }

        public float? Tax { get; set; }



        public int SalesID { get; set; }

        public string IpAddress { get; set; }

        // Mapping

        public Customer customer;
        public OrderCC ordercc;
        public OrderAddress orderAddress;
        public List<OrderLines> orderLines;


    }
```

Comment: What type is `orderLines` (we are missing class for OrderHeader), and have you made sure `orderLines` isn't null or empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AutoMapper map declaration is correct.

Can you verify that `ordersList.orderLines` is not `null` or empty before you map it?
It is possible that your `OrdersRepository` isn't giving or populating `ordersList` the way that you think it is.

```
IEnumerable<OrderHeader> ordersList = new OrdersRepository().getOrders();
// Check value of ordersList.orderLines.Count here
// (assuming orderLines is an IEnumerable<T>
```

---

**Update**

After verifying that `orderLines` is not empty, possible change `ProductsDTO` declaration to:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductsDTO> ProductsDTO { get; set; }
```

There is not a reason to specify it as `List<>`.  It is possible you are getting a type mismatch exception, because you aren't able to cast whatever `orderLines` is to a `List<>`

---

**Update 2**

You are trying to map `IEnumerable<OrderLines>` to `IEnumerable<ProductsDTO>`, which aren't congruant types.  Do you have a map for this also?

You need something like this as well:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderLine, ProductsDTO>().forMember(...
```

Comment: I debuged ordersList, and it returns correct collection. when i map a list then AutoMapper knows automatically? error I get is : An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Ok.  Is this exception new?  It isn't mentioned in your original question.  Also, is `orderLines` an `IEnumerable<ProductsDTO>`?

Comment: yes its IEnumerable, I updated my question please look at the orderHeader Class. Its same Exception.

Comment: All the Code I have I posted above already, I don't have any other mapping for OrderLines. I am new to AutoMapper.

Comment: Ok.  You need to specify how `OrderLines` converts to `ProductsDTO` as well.  You can specify a map for that as well, as shown in Update 2.  Cheers!

Comment: Just write me a quick line of code and I will pick it up from there, using automapper for first time today.

Comment: I updated to show an example map for this, but can't fill in the "..." without knowing what an `OrderLines` is.

Comment: Great! If property names and types are the same, you can exclude the `forMember` clauses because AutoMapper is smart enough to map those for you.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to Create a mapping to handle whatever class your `orderLines` collection  contains, to `ProductDTO`.  AutoMapper does't know how to handle those, so is ignoring them.

Comment: I address this in my answer.

Comment: @chadiusvt Apologies, I think I was typing my answer when you were updating yours. I didn't see it initially.